# Center of tree with weighted edges (possibly negative)

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm, weighted

I have seen this problem before for unweighted trees and trees with positive edge weights, but have not seen a solution for trees that could have negative weights.

For reference, the center of a tree is defined as the vertex that minimizes the maximum distance to any other vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly the same as a dynamic programming solution for a tree with positive edge weights. Let's run depth first search two times(we can pick an arbitrary vertex as a root). During the first phase, we will compute `distIn(v) = the longest distance from v to a vertex from the v's subtree.` I think this part is trivial(I can elaborate on this if necessary). During the second phase, we will compute the furthest vertex which is not inside the `v`'s subtree for all `v`. Let's call it `distOut(v)`. Here is a pseudo code for it:

```
void computeDistOut(v, pathFromParent) 
    distOut(v) = pathFromParent
    childDists = empty list
    for c : children of v
        childDists.add(distIn(c) + cost(v, c))
    for c : children of v
        maxDist = max among all distances from childDists except (distIn(c) + cost(v, c))
        computeDistOut(c, max(pathFromParent, maxDist) + cost(v, c))
```

The maximum distance from each vertex is `max(distIn(v), distOut(v))`. Now we can just pick a vertex that minimizes this value(it is a center by the definition).

About the time complexity: it is linear if this solution is implemented properly. Instead of maintaining a list of distances to all children(`childDists` in pseudo code), we can just store two maximum values among them. It allows us to get the `maxDist` value in `O(1)`(it is either the first or the second maximum).

Comment: For the first part, `the longest distance from v to a vertex from the v's subtree` this is just a DFS right? I also don't get what is meant by the `the furthest vertex which is not inside the v's subtree for all v`.

Comment: @1110101001 The first part: yes, it is just a dfs. For a fixed vertex `v` any other vertex is either inside `v`'s subtree or its not. The second part deals with those vertices that are not inside the `v`'s subtree(`v`'s subtree means a subtree rooted in `v`).